# Converting output to HTML format in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am learning PowerShell. During my experiments I used the following command:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> gci -path C:\windows\  | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -
gt "01-04-2011"} | Format-List -property Fullname | ConvertTo-Html | out-file E:
\PowerShell\Out.html
```

I expected the output like the one displayed in the console (like:FullName:C:\Windows...). But when I open the Out.html it has some strange things like:

> ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e    pageHeaderEntry pageFooterEntry autosizeInfo    shapeInfo   groupingEntry

What am I missing here?

Comment: Shouldnt you use `Format-Table` or `Select-Object` in place of `Format-List`? Or you should append `ConvertTo-Html` directly after the `Where-Object`

Comment: I tried `Format-Table` too..didn't make any difference.

Comment: Try appending `ConvertTo-Html` directly after `where-object`

Comment: @empo: You were right..instead of `Format-List` I should use `Select-Object`. If you can post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `select-object` in place of `format-list`.

Answer (score 2):

[Handle Formatted Output in PowerShell](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2011/05/11/handle-formatted-output-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd:
powershell gci -path %windir% ^| ?{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date -Year 2011 -Month 04 -Day 01)} ^| Format-List -property Fullname | more


PS>gci -path %windir% | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date -Year 2011 -Month 04 -Day 01)} | Format-List -property Fullname | more
```